# Short-cut in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to write a text editor.

I'd need to:

- be able to understand what text is selected so that a shortcut could work in the correct portion of text, just like in this editor, if I select a word in the middle of the text and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- Be able to catch when some keys are pressed like this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Reverse Engineering the WMD Editor](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/). That's the editor used on SO and supports what you're referring to. The function that augments the current text selection as **Bold** is called `doBorI()`. Search for it in the source.

As for catching keyboard events, [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html) has a great primer on that, including detecting which key has been pressed.

Not sure what your specific question is exactly, but hopefully those are good starts.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at one of the existing editors to see how they handle this.

I recently started using: [JWysiwyg](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/), which has the advantage of being a very concise code-base and hence easier to decipher.

Comment: That very much complex than what I need, I'm not going to do a wysiwyg, and it will even be an editor for posts/comments. I need it  for a particular language. I'd like to understand just how to do those 2 things. Anyway, if you say it's easy to read I'll have a look, thanks!